# Disabling change folder in CFileDialog in MFC at certain case

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, directory, visual-c++-2008

I am trying to overload the CFiledialog class to add functionalities as per my need. I am not getting the solution for restricting user from changing folder in certain situation as mentioned below.

When user is attempting to change folder.

- I need to check if there any folder is selected or not?
- If selected I need to check, if any of the selected folder is containing the desired file or not?
- If the selected folder is having the desired file, then in such case I want to disable the change folder functionality.

I have tried to override `virtual void  OnFolderChange();` function, but call to this function comes after the folder is already changed.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I think, the CFiledialog class is not designed to do this, why do you need this? Maybe there is some alternative component or stategy

Comment: I just need to override the default implementation of "Open" button of CFileDialog.

If a folder is selected, I need to check if this folder has file of desired type or not, If yes, then it must not open the selected folder and just closes the dialog.

Is it possible to override default implementation of Open button handler, as i have subclassed the CFileDialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overridden the default handler for IDOK(ie Open button). Same as explained in the article in the link below.

http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/toolbar/miscellaneous/article.php/c5497/Adding-Toolbar-button-in-CFileDialog.htm